# предпросмотр и загрузка картинок на сервер

Tags: php, javascript, изображения

Подскажите, в каком направлении двигаться. Нужно сделать загрузку картинок и сразу же их предпросмотр и простое редактирование (crop, rotate). А теперь вопросы. Возможно ли организовать загрузку, предпросмотр и это редактирование полностью на стороне клиента, а выгрузку на сервер (а точнее на Яндекс диск) после нажатия кнопки «загрузить»? На данном этапе сделал загрузку и предпросмотр на html5. И если редактирование возможно на стороне клиента, то такой вопрос: как в сессию сохранить сами картинки (или ссылки на них) и все пользовательские действия (rotate, crop), чтобы при уходе со страницы это сохранилось? или не париться и сделать сразу нагрузку на облако в какую-нибудь папку вроде «временная» в подпапку с session id? или же я совсем не в том направлении копаю?

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужна обрезка и прочее, я бы посоветовал данный плагин:

https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/

В примерах есть загрузка на сервер, предосмотр, и т.д.